# Do not display permission window if app already authorized facebook sdk android app

Tags: android, facebook

I have a facebook login feature in my app. Now everything works fine. My only concern is that, when the app is already authorized, meaning all permission were already granted. I do not want to display the window that say, "You have already authorized this app". Is there a possible way to do this?

Right now this is my Auth Button's settings.

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setFragment(this);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email", "user_birthday"));
authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

Also another reason why I do not want to show this is because, sometimes when I'm at the permission screen after logging in, the loading dialog takes a while to close. Sometimes it's not even closing. I don't know if this is a bug or I did something wrong. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I see. Any thoughts on why sometimes the permission screen loading dialog takes a while to close?

Answer (score 0):

I use the FB SDK as well in one of my apps. Maybe if I share with you the behavior of the SDK in my app with you, you'll be able to determine if it is by design, or not.

The FB SDK will only give you that message when you log into the app and it does not know if you have logged in before. The first time you log in, it will ask you if you want it to remember the browser,or in your case the app.

Once you give it permission and you log out of your app and re-log back in, an empty window pops up momentarily and the sign in button displays the "Log Out.

If you I go into my FB account to "Settings->Apps->" and delete the app. It will reproduce the behavior above.

Hope that helps. Feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: I have the same behavior with my app. Now my question is if there's a way to skip the permission part once already authorized. But I think this is by design. Now the only problem I've been wanting to solve is the permission part, where the loading dialog takes a while to close. Any thoughts?

Comment: It doesn't ask me unless I lose the OATH data. Like I said above, a blank window pops up momentarily but that is all. The only time I see the message you're describing is if I uninstall my app and re-install it. Besides that, I do not get that message. Also, I tested it by uninstalling the FB app and then re-installing it. The behavior was similar.
Not sure why you're seeing everytime.

Comment: That's weird. I'm using the authButton form the tutorial from the facebook sdk. I did not add anything.

Comment: The log in button you're talking about takes care of the OAUTH stuff in the background. Do you have the Facebook app installed on the phone/device?

Comment: I removed this line authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO); this force the user to not utilize the facebook app.